# Excel - Find duplicates in one column then sum quantities into another column?

Tags: excel

[Find duplicates in one column then sum quantities into another column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AADjd.png)

```
DATA       RESULT   

A  1       A  11
A  1       B  7
A  9       C  5
B  2       D  4
B  2       E  8
B  3            
C  5            
D  4            
E  7            
E  1
```

Comment: [COUNTIF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif)

Comment: Pivot Table or Power Query

Comment: I have tried countif, but I have not come up with anything that works. But that maybe down to my incompency.

Comment: Sorry, it's the [SUMIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b). I always confuse them. If you still can't make it work, give me the addresses of the ranges you are working with (the DATA and RESULT lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: This is about our tool esProc. We have been told it’s an easy and obvious way to Group Excel Worksheets.

```
A1=file("D:/data.xlsx").xlsimport()
A2=A1.groups(_1;sum(_2))
A3=file("D:/result.xlsx").xlsexport(A2)
```

More detail see this post:[Group & Summarize an XLS file without Using Excel](https://esprocforbp.medium.com/group-summarize-an-xls-file-without-using-excel-9b6f8ed8d06)

Answer (score 0):

For **EXCEL 365** *(or the Excel web app)*:

In **C1** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A10)
```

in **D1** enter:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,C1#,B1:B10)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If VBA is acceptable to you, then try:

```
Public Function unikue(rng As Range)
    Dim arr, c As Collection, r As Range
    Dim nCall As Long, nColl As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    
    nCall = Application.Caller.Count
    
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In rng
            c.Add r.Text, CStr(r.Text)
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    nColl = c.Count
    
    
    If nCall > nColl Then
        ReDim arr(1 To nCall, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To nCall
            arr(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To nColl, 1 To 1)
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To nColl
        arr(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i
    
    unikue = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortuneatly 'UNIQUE' does not appear as a function in my office 2019. I know you refer to Excel 365, but ?? any ideas plz

Comment: I will sort out alternative to UNIQUE, and =SUMIF(A1:A10,C1:C5,B1:B10) works fine, just copy down to D5. I think I will use VBA to accomplish all. Many thanks for help.

Comment: @user10127073  See my **EDIT#1**