# Split Text By every Nth Delimiter and Transpose Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to extract text from a block of text. The block looks like this:

`{"some text"},{"some more text"},{"some other"},{"some other text"},{"let's add more"},{"even more other text"}`

The text is supposed to be in pairs so that the first and second {""},{""} go into the same cell and so forth. I tried the split function but since the delimiter is a comma I am not able to split in pairs. So I need to split after every 2 commas and put the resulting pair in it's own cell. Then Transpose the result so that the text goes inside a column vertically.

I tried `=SPLIT("",",")` but didn't get the desired output.

I am using Google sheets for this and would like to do this inside Google Sheets, but I'm open to doing this inside Excel.

If you want to have a look at the Google Sheets File, here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbK6nF-6SO4oOKTdercgnfHGeQol-vfV5SRcFXNBy5o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome, consider adding a ascii table like ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63837444) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64182673/)) or screenshots or csv text(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186520/)) to show your data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting and fun query.

In `B2`, see if the following formula works for you:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"([^,]+,[^,]+),","$1|"),"|"))
```

The regular expression can be made more specific to target only those comma's in between curly brackets if need be.

---

**Edit**

To `SPLIT` your desired outcome into two columns ***and*** get rid of the curly brackets and outer quotes I came up with:

```
=TRANSPOSE({SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"{""([^,]+)""},{""([^,]+)""}(?:,|$)","$1|"),"|");SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"{""([^,]+)""},{""([^,]+)""}(?:,|$)","$2|"),"|")})
```

Comment: Added this to D2 ```=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(C2:C="","",(split(C2:C,","))),"{",""),"}",""),"""",""))``` Thanks to your formula, I have separated the text but I'm not able to make it into one single formula. I wanted to manipulate your formula a little further but I can't. If you have a moment, please see my attempt in D2.

Comment: @maryongubo, I answered that to the best of my GS knowledge.

Comment: That is the formula I was looking for and you nailed it! Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not tolerate commas inside the strings.

Answer (score 0):

To adapt the solution for `ARRAYFORMULA` we just need to join all the strings with comma.

A few notes on the following solution:

With `REGEXREPLACE` we strip all the surrounding `{"..."}`. At the same time we replace every even comma (not just every comma, but the ones between records, e.g. commas inside the strings won't be affected) with `"♠"` for later splitting pairs into the separate strings, and every odd comma we replace with `"♥"` for later splitting a pair into two strings.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SPLIT(
    TRANSPOSE(
      SPLIT(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          TEXTJOIN(
            ",",
            True,
            A2:A
          ),
          "\{""(.*?)""\},\{""(.*?)""\},?",
          "$1♥$2♠"
        ),
        "♠"
      )
    ),
    "♥"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: The strings that I'm dealing with won't be having any commas, but I must agree that the above is a safe way, just in case. I have stumbled into another challenge. Some strings don't have a match so they won't be in pairs. I wish to add an empty pair for the string which doesn't have it's match. Ideally, the first of the pair will have a number between 1-20 while the second is basically text. Example - ```{"This doesn't change":"2"},{"This doesn't change":"This changes"},``` But there are cases where the second of the pair is ```{"This doesn't change":"This changes"}``` only. See document link

Comment: @maryongubo could you show how that looks in a shhet?

Comment: The link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbK6nF-6SO4oOKTdercgnfHGeQol-vfV5SRcFXNBy5o/edit#gid=891711070

Comment: While this might be a unique case, I hope this answer by @kishkin could be of some help to someone. ```=ARRAYFORMULA(
  SPLIT(
    TRANSPOSE(
      SPLIT(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          TEXTJOIN(
            ",",
            True,
            A2:A
          ),
          "(?:\{""yellow and red"":""(\d*)""\},)?\{""yellow and red"":""(.*?)""\},?",
          "$1♥$2♠"
        ),
        "♠"
      )
    ),
    "♥",
    True,
    False
  )
)```

Comment: I'm trying to revert the order from ```Number, Name``` to ```Name, Number```. I changed the formula but it appears I'm missing something. ` =ARRAYFORMULA(
  SPLIT(
    TRANSPOSE(
      SPLIT(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          TEXTJOIN(
            ",",
            True,
            A1:A
          ),
          "\{""yellow and home team"":""(.*?)""\},?","$1♥$2♠?(?:\{""yellow and home team"":""(\d*)""\},)"
        ),
        "♠"
      )
    ),
    "♥",
    True,
    False
  )
)`

Comment: had to use `[^"]`: `=ARRAYFORMULA( SPLIT( TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( REGEXREPLACE( TEXTJOIN( ",", True, A1:A ), "\{""[^""]*"":""([^""]*)""\},?(?:\{""[^""]*"":""(\d*)""\},?)?", "$1♥$2♠" ), "♠" ) ), "♥", True, False ) )`